# What does "???" mean in x32dbg?

Tags: debugging

I see such things but I just couldn't understand. Do you have any ideas?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Yea, as defrager answered, looks to me like a disassembled data segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that there is no valid opcode for this spot. The other 'valid' opcodes in your picture look also not useful at all. I assume the whole block there is nothing that can be executed.